# How low into the latitude may ice shelves reach?

Tags: climate, geography

I am currently working on the effects of glaciers on my continents. My main source is [Madeline James](https://www.madelinejameswrites.com/blog/glaciers-and-physiographic-regions), a bit of [Worldbuilding Pasta](https://worldbuildingpasta.blogspot.com/2020/05/an-apple-pie-from-scratch-part-vib.html#icecapssketch), and Google.

[image]

My question is the title. Would the area circled in red have glaciers and an ice shelf or, for some reason I haven't found, would it not? The blue line across the map is the last glacial maximum I am trying to work with. But I don't know if it is reaching too far because the continent doesn't even go to the 50th degree. The latitudes are on the right. The map is of the southern hemisphere. During the last Ice Age on Earth the ice shelves reached as far as 40 to 30 degrees north. This planet has a similar axial tilt, mass, size, and atmosphere to Earth.

Comment: During the Last Glacial Maximum, the Cape province in South Africa at 34° south, and the southernmost parts of Greater Australia at 42° south, and most of the United New Zealand at 44° south (except the high mountains in the south) were ice-free. In southermost South America, the high mountains in the west were glaciated, but the lowlands in the east were ice-free.

Comment: Consider studying about the [snowball Earth hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_Earth).

Comment: @JBH I have heard of this before but never explored it much. So I shouldn’t have glaciers pass the 30th degree north or south or else I will have a frozen wasteland of a planet. It could have happened elsewhere in my planet’s history but I am only working on the latest ice age. It does help but not really with my question. Thank you. It was an interesting read.

Comment: @AlexP But could the ice spread along the island chains connecting the continents and cause an ice shelf to form on the middle continent?

Comment: While my knowledge may be limited in such a topic. I don't see any problem why why it should not be possible as long as the temperature is cold enough and there is enough water to form it.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider that over long time periods, continents move due to tectonic drift, it is entirely possible that several ice age cycles ago, your continent could have been in the far north or south of the world.
Alternatively, it could also be possible that there was much fewer pollutants and greenhouse gases in your world in the last ice age cycle that would decrease the albedo effect on ice sheets which would increase the chance of temperatures becoming cold enough to cause a global ice age